# Naturally linear Diophantine equations

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

A linear [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) in two variables is an equation of the form **ax + by = c**, where **a**, **b** and **c** are constant integers and **x** and **y** are integer variables.

For many naturally occurring Diophantine equations, **x** and **y** represent quantities that cannot be negative.

#### Task

Write a program or function that accepts the coefficients **a**, **b** and **c** as input and returns an arbitrary pair of **natural numbers** (0, 1, 2, …) **x** and **y** that verify the equation **ax + by = c**, if such a pair exists.

#### Additional rules

- You can choose any format for input and output that involves only the desired integers and, optionally, array/list/matrix/tuple/vector notation of your language, as long as you don't embed any code in the input.
- You may assume that the coefficients **a** and **b** are both non-zero.
- Your code must work for any triplet of integers between **-2<sup>60</sup>** and **2<sup>60</sup>**; it must finish in under a minute on my machine (Intel i7-3770, 16 GiB RAM).
- You may not use any built-ins that solve Diophantine equations and thus trivialize this task, such as Mathematica's [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) or [`FrobeniusSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html).
- Your code may behave however you want if no solution can be found, as long as it complies with the time limit and its output cannot be confused with a valid solution.
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

#### Examples

1. The examples below illustrate valid I/O for the equation **2x + 3y = 11**, which has exactly two valid solutions ( **(x,y) = (4,1)** and **(x,y) = (1,3)** ).

   ```
   Input:  2 3 11
   Output: [4 1]

   Input:  (11 (2,3))
   Output: [3],(1)
   ```
2. The only valid solution of **2x + 3y = 2** is the pair **(x,y) = (1,0)**.
3. The examples below illustrate valid I/O for the equation **2x + 3y = 1**, which has **no valid solutions**.

   ```
   Input:  (2 3 1)
   Output: []

   Input:  1 2 3
   Output: -1

   Input:  [[2], [3], [1]]
   Output: (2, -1)
   ```
4. For **(a, b, c) = (1152921504606846883, -576460752303423433, 1)**, all correct solutions **(x,y)** satisfy that **(x,y) = (135637824071393749 - bn, 271275648142787502 + an)** for some non-negative integer **n**.

Comment: I think it might be good to place a bit more emphasis on nonnegative integers, and that the second example in fact has no solution.

Comment: intput 1 2 3 has a valid output though... [ 1, 1 ]

Comment: @JackAmmo: All examples in the second code block correspond to **2x + 3y = 1**.

Comment: In ax+bx=k it seems to me to understand that the solution has to be x>=0 and y>=0. So who are such x,y>=0 solutions of 38*x+909*y=3?

Comment: In such case probably I have to return that not exist solution...

Comment: @RosLuP *Your code may behave however you want if no solution can be found, as long as it complies with the time limit and its output cannot be confused with a valid solution.* The third list item of the **Examples** section shows some possible outputs. Crashing would also be acceptable.

Comment: Test cases are few, 'crashing' or raise exceptions should be something never to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 92 bytes

```
I!%vzhK%2u?sm,ed-hd*ed/F<G2cG2@G1G+~Q,hQ_eQj9 2)J*L/vzhKtKeoSNm-VJ/RhK_*LdQsm+LdtM3/V*LhK_JQ
```

It's quite a monster.

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=I!%25vzhK%252u%3Fsm%2Ced-hd*ed%2FF%3CG2cG2%40G1G%2B~Q%2ChQ_eQj9+2)J*L%2FvzhKtKeoSNm-VJ%2FRhK_*LdQsm%2BLdtM3%2FV*LhK_JQ&input=11%0A%5B2%2C+3%5D&debug=0). The input format is `c\n[a,b]` and the output format is `[x,y]`.

In the case that no integer solution exists, I'll print nothing, and in the case that no natural integer solution exists, I'll simply print a random integer solution.

#### Explanation (Rough Overview)

1. At first I'll find an integer solution to the equation `ax + by = gcd(a,b)` by using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.
2. Then I'll modify the solution (my multiplying `a` and `b` with `c/gcd(a,b)`) to get an integer solution of `ax + by = c`. This works, if `c/gcd(a,b)` is an integer. Otherwise there doesn't exist a solution.
3. All the other integer solutions have the form `a(x+n*b/d) + b(y-n*a/d) = c`  with `d = gcd(a,b)` for integer `n`. Using the two inequalities `x+n*b/d >= 0` and `y-n*a/d >= 0` I can determine 6 possible values for `n`. I'll try all 6 of them and print the solution with the highest lowest coefficient.

#### Explanation (Detailed)

The first step is to find an integer solution to the equation `ax' + by' = gcd(a,b)`. This can be done by using the extended Euclidean algorithm. You can get an idea on how it works at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Example). The only difference is, that instead of using 3 columns (`r_i s_i t_i`) I'll use 6 columns (`r_i-1 r_i s_i-1 s_i t_i-1 t_i`). This way I don't have to keep the last two rows in memory, only the last one.

```
K%2u?sm,ed-hd*ed/F<G2cG2@G1G+~Q,hQ_eQj9 2)   implicit: Q = [a,b] (from input)
                                     j9 2    convert 9 to base 2: [1,0,0,1]
                            + Q              add to Q => [a,b,1,0,0,1]
                                             this is the initial row
   u                                     )   start with G = ^ and update G repeatedly
                                             by the following expression, until
                                             the value of G doesn't change anymore
    ?                   @G1                    if G[1] != 0:
                     cG2                         split G into parts of 2
      m                                          map the parts d to:
       ,                                           the pair 
        ed                                           d[1]
          -hd*ed/F<G2                                d[0]-d[1]*G[0]/G[1]
     s                                           unfold
                                               else:
                           G                     G (don't change it, stop criterion for u)
 %2                                          take every second element
                                             we get the list [gcd(a,b),x',y']
K                                            store this list in K
                             ~Q,hQ_eQ        afterwards change Q to [Q[0],-Q[1]] = [a,-b]
                                             This will be important for the other parts.
```

Now I want to find a solution to `ax + by = c`. This is possible only, when `c mod gcd(a,b) == 0`. If this equation is satisfied, I simply multiplying `x',y'` with `c/gcd(a,b)`.

```
I!%vzhK...J*L/vzhKtK   implicit: z = c in string format (from input)
  %vzhK                evaluated(z) mod K[0] (=gcd(a,b))
I!                     if not ^ than: 
             /vzhK        c/K[0]
           *L     tK      multipy ^ to each element in K[1:] (=[x',y'])
          J               and store the result in J, this is now [x,y]
```

We have an integer solution for `ax + by = c`. Notice, that `x`, `y` or both may be negative. So our goal is to transform these to non-negative.

The nice thing about Diophantine equations is, that we can describe all solution using only one initial solution. If `(x,y)` is a solution, that all other solutions are of the form `(x-n*b/gcd(a,b),y+n*a/gcd(a,b))` for `n` integer.

Therefore we want to find a `n`, where `x-n*b/gcd(a,b) >= 0` and `y+n*a/gcd(a,b >= 0`. After some transformation we end up with the two inequalities `n >= -x*gcd(a,b)/b` and `n >= y*gcd(a,b)/a`. Notice that the inequality symbol might look in the other direction due the division with a potential negative `a` or `b`. I don't care that much about it, I simply say that one number of `-x*gcd(a,b)/b - 1, -x*gcd(a,b)/b, -x*gcd(a,b)/b + 1` definitly satisfies inequality 1, and one number of `y*gcd(a,b)/a - 1, y*gcd(a,b)/a, y*gcd(a,b)/a + 1` satisfies inequality 2. It there is a `n`, that satisfies both inequalities, one of the 6 numbers also does.

Then I calculate the new solutions `(x-n*b/gcd(a,b),y+n*a/gcd(a,b))` for all 6 possible values of `n`. And I print the solution with the highest lowest value.

```
eoSNm-VJ/RhK_*LdQsm+LdtM3/V*LhK_JQ
                               _J    reverse J => [y,x]
                           *LhK      multiply each value with K[0] => [y*gcd,x*gcd]
                         /V      Q   vectorized division => [y*gcd/a,-x*gcd/b]
                  m                  map each d of ^ to:
                      tM3              [-1,0,1]
                   +Ld                 add d to each ^
                 s                   unfold
                                     these are the possible values for n
    m                                map each d (actually n) of ^ to:
             *LdQ                      multiply d to Q => [a*n,-b*n]
            _                          reverse => [-b*n,a*n]
        /RhK                           divide by K[0] => [-b*n/gcd,a*n/gcd]
     -VJ                               vectorized subtraction with J
                                       => [x+b*n/gcd,y-a*n/gcd]
 oSN                                 order the solutions by their sorted order
e                                    print the last one
```

The sort by their sorted order thing works the following way. I'm using the example `2x + 3y = 11`

I sort each of the 6 solutions (this are called keys), and sort the original solutions by their keys:

```
solutions: [1, 3], [4, 1], [7, -1], [-5, 7], [-2, 5], [1, 3]
keys:      [1, 3], [1, 4], [-1, 7], [-5, 7], [-2, 5], [1, 3]
sort by key:
solutions: [-5, 7], [-2, 5], [7, -1], [1, 3], [1, 3], [4, 1]
keys:      [-5, 7], [-2, 5], [-1, 7], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4]
```

This sorts a complete non-negative solution to the end (if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

- after Dennis' remarks, that made my previous idea upside-down, i had to change the code from its roots and it took me long term debugging, and cost me twice n° of bytes :'(.

### Matlab (660)

```
a=input('');b=input('');c=input('');if((min(a*c,b*c)>c*c)&&a*c>0&&b*c>0)||(a*c<0&&b*c<0),-1,return,end,g=abs(gcd(a,b));c=c/g;a=a/g;b=b/g;if(c~=floor(c)),-1,return,end,if(c/a==floor(c/a)&&c/a>0),e=c/a-b;if(e>0),e,a,return,else,c/a,0,return,end,end,if(c/b==floor(c/b)&&c/b>0),e=c/b-a;if(e>0),b,e,return,else,0,c/b,return,end,end,f=max(abs(a),abs(b));if f==abs(a),f=b;b=a;a=f;g=0.5;end,e=(c-b)/a;f=(c-2*b)/a;if(e<0&&f<e),-1,elseif(e<0&&f>e),for(i=abs(c*a):abs((c+1)*a)),e=(c-i*b);if(mod(e,a)==0)if(g==0.5),i,e/a;else,e/a,i,end,return,end,end,else for(i=1:abs(a)),e=(c-i*b);if(e/a<0),-1,elseif(mod(e,a)==0),if(g==0.5),i,e/a,else,e/a,i,end,return,end,end,end,-1
```

> - Well , i know its not golfed, since that type of languages isnt adapted for code length reduction, but, i can ensure that time-complexity is at its best.

### Explanation:

- the code takes three invariants a,b,c as input, these last ones are subdued to couple of conditions before proceeding to calculate:

  1- if (a+b>c) and (a,b,c>0) no solution!

  2- if (a+b < c) ,(a,b,c<0) no solution!

  3- if (a, b) have common opposite signs of c : no solution!

  4- if GCD(a,b) dosnt divide c, then no solution again! , otherwise, divide all variants by GCD.
- after this , we have to check another condition out, it should ease and shorteb the way to desired solution.

  5- if c divide a or b , solution s= (x or y)=(c-[ax,yb])/[b,a]=C/[b,a]+[ax,yb]/[b,a]=S+[ax,yb]/[b,a] where S is natural so ax/b or by/a would have henceforth non-negative direct solutions which are respectively x=b or y=a . (notice that solutions can be just nil values in case previous arbitrary solutions are revealed negatives)
- when the program reaches this stage, a narrower range of solutions for x=(c-yb)/a is swept instead, thanks to congruence, of sweeping larger ranges of numbers ,which is come accross repetitively by regular cycles. the largest search field is [x-a,x+a] where a is the divisor.

### [TRY IT](http://rextester.com/NDXGP44424)

Comment: euuh , large numbers issue , gonna fix that (wonder when lol)

Comment: I think its still minor bug to fix, about large integers, i still dont get why dividing 1152921504606846800.000000/576460752303423420.000000 comes out with natural number 2 ,though this last result is rounded .

Comment: ohh . i forgot to fix that bugging bug :p thanks for noticing it @Jakube

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 460 bytes

```
w(a,b,x,u)==(a=0=>[b,x];w(b rem a,a,u,x-u*(b quo a)))
d(a,b,k)==(o:List List INT:=[];a=0 and b=0=>(k=0=>[1,1];[]);a=0=>(k=0=>[[1,0]];k rem b=0=>[1,k quo b];[]);b=0=>(k=0=>[[0,1]];k rem a=0=>[k quo a,1];[]);r:=w(a,b,0,1);q:=k quo r.1;(y,x,u,v):=(q*(r.1-r.2*a)quo b,q*r.2,b quo r.1,a quo r.1);m:=min(80,4+abs(k)quo min(abs(a),abs(b)));l:=y quo v;x:=x+l*u;y:=y-l*v;for n in -m..m repeat(t:=x+n*u;z:=y-n*v;t>=0 and z>=0 and t*a+z*b=k=>(o:=cons([t,z],o)));sort(o))
```

ungolf and some test

```
-- input a b and k for equation a*x+b*y=k
-- result one List of List of elments [x,y] of solution of  
-- that equation with x and y NNI (not negative integers) 
-- or Void list [] for no solution
diopanto(a,b,k)==
  o:List List INT:=[]
  a=0 and b=0=>(k=0=>[1,1];[])
  a=0=>(k=0=>[[1,0]];k rem b=0=>[1,k quo b];[])
  b=0=>(k=0=>[[0,1]];k rem a=0=>[k quo a,1];[])
  r:=w(a,b,0,1)
  q:=k quo r.1
  (y,x,u,v):=(q*(r.1-r.2*a)quo b,q*r.2,b quo r.1,a quo r.1)
  m:=min(80,4+abs(k)quo min(abs(a),abs(b)))
  l:=y quo v           -- center the interval
  x:=x+l*u; y:=y-l*v
  for n in -m..m repeat
     t:=x+n*u;z:=y-n*v
     t>=0 and z>=0 and t*a+z*b=k=>(o:=cons([t,z],o))
  sort(o)

 ------------------------------------------------------
(4) -> d(0,-9,0)
   (4)  [[1,0]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
(5) -> d(2,3,11)
   (5)  [[4,1],[1,3]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
(6) -> d(2,3,2)
   (6)  [[1,0]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
(7) -> d(2,3,1)
   (7)  []
                                                  Type: List List Integer
(8) -> d(1152921504606846883,-576460752303423433,1)
   (8)
   [[135637824071393749,271275648142787502],
    [712098576374817182,1424197152749634385],
    [1288559328678240615,2577118657356481268],
    [1865020080981664048,3730040161963328151],
    [2441480833285087481,4882961666570175034]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
```

In the other 'solutions' possible there was a bug because
it tried to save the infinite solutions in one List; now it is
imposed the limit of 80 solutions max